# F1-score per class for multi-class classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on a multiclass classification problem using python and scikit-learn. Currently, I'm using the `classification_report` function to evaluate the performance of my classifier, obtaining reports like the following:

```
>>> print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

    class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
    class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
    class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

avg / total       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

To do further analysis, I'm interesting in obtaining the per-class f1 score of each of the classes available. Maybe something like this:

```
>>> print(calculate_f1_score(y_true, y_pred, target_class='class 0'))
0.67
```

Is there something like that available on scikit-learn?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Taken from the `f1_score` [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html).

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]

f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None)
```

Ouputs:

```
array([ 0.8,  0. ,  0. ])
```

Which is the scores for each class.

Comment: Is there a way to get a mapping of which F1 score corresponds to which Label?

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `f1_score` along with the `labels` argument

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
labels = [0, 1, 2]

f1_scores = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None, labels=labels)
f1_scores_with_labels = {label:score for label,score in zip(labels, f1_scores)}
```

Outputs:

```
{0: 0.8, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0}
```

Comment: As a little enhancement:     f1_scores_with_labels = dict(zip(labels, f1_scores))

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use pos_label as parameter and assign the class value which you want to print.

```
f1_score(ytest, ypred_prob, pos_label=0)# default is pos_label=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the confusion matrix `C`, with rows corresponding to predictions and columns corresponding to truth, you can compute F1 score using the following function:

```
def f1(C):
    num_classes = np.shape(C)[0]
    f1_score = np.zeros(shape=(num_classes,), dtype='float32')
    weights = np.sum(C, axis=0)/np.sum(C)

    for j in range(num_classes):
        tp = np.sum(C[j, j])
        fp = np.sum(C[j, np.concatenate((np.arange(0, j), np.arange(j+1, num_classes)))])
        fn = np.sum(C[np.concatenate((np.arange(0, j), np.arange(j+1, num_classes))), j])
#         tn = np.sum(C[np.concatenate((np.arange(0, j), np.arange(j+1, num_classes))), np.concatenate((np.arange(0, j), np.arange(j+1, num_classes)))])

        precision = tp/(tp+fp) if (tp+fp) > 0 else 0
        recall = tp/(tp+fn) if (tp+fn) > 0 else 0
        f1_score[j] = 2*precision*recall/(precision + recall)*weights[j] if (precision + recall) > 0 else 0

    f1_score = np.sum(f1_score)
    return f1_score
```

Answer (score 0):

### Separate F1 scores for each class, from a confusion matrix

NumPy operations on a confusion matrix are not terribly complex, so if you don't want or need to include the scikit-learn dependency, you can achieve all these results with only NumPy.

```py
import numpy as np
C = make_confusion_matrix(data, labels, num_classes) # exercise for the reader
```

The typical explanation for F1 first classifies each item in the confusion matrix as one of `true positive`, `false positive`, or `false negative`:

```py
TP = np.diag(C)      # true positive
FP = C.sum(1) - TP   # false positive
precision = TP / (TP + FP)

FN = C.sum(0) - TP   # false negative
recall = TP / (TP + FN)
```

Recognizing that `precision = TP / (TP - TP + C.sum(1))` we can simplify to `precision = TP / C.sum(1)`. We can simplify the recall calculation similarly, resulting in this F1 calculation for each class:

```py
TP = np.diag(C)              # true positives
precision = TP/C.sum(1)
recall = TP/C.sum(0)
F1c = (2*precision*recall) / (precision+recall) # per-class F1 score
```

### micro-averaged F1 score

For some use cases individual class F1 scores are all you need, but we can also compute a *micro-averaged* F1 score to summarize the quality across all classes with a single number.

> Micro-averaged F-measure gives equal weight to each document and is therefore considered as an average over all the document/category pairs. It tends to be dominated by the classifier’s performance on common categories. [link](https://www.cmpe.boun.edu.tr/%7Egungort/papers/Text%20Categorization%20with%20Class-Based%20and%20Corpus-Based%20Keyword%20Selection.pdf)

```py
precision_micro = TP.sum() / C.sum(1).sum()
recall_micro = TP.sum() / C.sum(0).sum()
micro_F1 = (2*precision_micro*recall_micro) / (precision_micro+recall_micro)
```

But if we note that `C.sum(1).sum() == C.sum(0).sum() == C.sum()` this simplifies to

```py
# pm = TP.sum() / C.sum()  # micro precision
# rm = TP.sum() / C.sum()  # micro recall
m = TP.sum() / C.sum()   # just use one variable since pm == rm
micro_F1 = (2*m*m) / (m+m)
#        = ((2*m)*m) / (2*m)  # factor (2*m) from numerator and denominator
#        = m
```

### macro-averaged F1 score

Similar to the *micro-averaged* F1 score, we can also compute a *macro-averaged* F1 score, which gives a different perspective about the overall performance of the model.

> Macro-averaged F-measure gives equal weight to each category, regardless of its frequency. It is influenced more by the classifier’s performance on rare categories. [link](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.8244&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

This is the mean of the per-class F1 scores defined as `F1c` above:

```py
F1c.mean()
```

#### What about zeros in the denominator?

The `sklearn.metrics.f1_score` function has an option called `zero_division` so you can choose a replacement value in
case the denominator contains zeros. We can replicate this by adding `np.nan_to_num` to the division operations:

```py
nan_fill_value = 0
precision = np.nan_to_num(TP/C.sum(1), nan_fill_value)
# same for each denominator that may contain zeros
```